# What are the fundamental limits to the temperature produced by computation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, computational-physics, computer

Wikipedia has a list of limits to computation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits_of_computation

These limits seem to mostly be really high bounds based on entropy considerations and so on, but a much lower limit I'm wondering about is how cool you can keep a computer made out of regular matter when you are operating it with higher and higher specs. Forget the other kind of limitations you can reach by using a black hole or a degenerate star to do computations, and stick to having a good old solid hyper-desktop of the future. Now first of all, Silicon has a maximum operating temperature of 125 degrees celsius. We can imagine various replacements to Silicon, but even in the most absurd scenario, no solid computer can ever become as hot as the melting point of Tungsten (3422 degrees c).

There must be a limit to the amount you can minimize waste heat per a certain unit of computation. I don't really understand Landauer's Principle here. It says that erasing bits requires entropy increases in the environment, but then the wikipedia article goes on to say that "reversible computing" gets around that, and I quote: "A so-called logically-reversible computation, in which no information is erased, may in principle be carried out without releasing any heat."

I can't say I understand how you can perform any action without releasing heat, though in context I guess that it's saying that you avoid the heat associated with erasing information, but creating it in the first place would still create heat. So I want to know what the fundamental limit on *that* is. If you create a bit of information, there's going to be some minimum physical law that governs how efficient, and therefore how cool that process can be.

To quantify the question to a concrete example: How much information could you process in, say, the equivalent of a reasonable computer case volume (45L?), before the waste heat is going to melt even tungsten? I think that would represent a comfortable margin beyond the fundamental physics limit even for futuristic computers (outside of wacky schemes involving black holes that are mentioned on wiki).

Comment: The problem with asking about "practical" or "reasonable" limits is that they depend a great deal on what you consider practical and reasonable. For example you say that no solid state computer could operate about the melting point of tungsten, but the number you quote is only correct at a specific pressure. Is it "reasonable" to operate my computer in a diamond anvil cell, where the melting point of many materials will be higher? What I suspect you will find in this case is that your limits are determined more by what you consider to be allowed than by any particularly deep physics.

Comment: In terms of Landauer's Principle and reversible computing, reversible computing "gets round" Landauers principle by simply never erasing any data, so there is no contradiction here. (obviously never erasing data is a very significant limitation)

Comment: @BySymmetry - I thought pressure might come up, but I'm allowing for standard pressure operation only here. It's interesting what you're saying about reversible computing. You seem to be implying that it has some limitations comparatively.